# Firestore write data missing

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this code, and it is supposed to write to Firestore. However, when it does the function, in the back end, it shows highlighted as red and then disappears.

```
    db.collection("jokes").document("Dad Jokes").setData(["\(dadJokeNum + 1)": Joke.text!])
```

Please help.

Comment: The code in this question (as is) will not cause that issue. The code you previously had, which wrote additional data to the exact same document with a `merge=false` clause *would* cause this issue. The accepted answer only applies in those cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SetData without Merge will delete existing values - it is suggested that if the document exists prior, you should always be using `merge: true`. Firestore also has a limited 1 write per second each, you should be managing writes together as it is most likely similar writes will conflict and potentially resolve out of order.

Comment: Thank you. However, as you may have seen by my edit, I am focused on the line of code creating a field in a document.

Comment: For future readers: OP changed the question so while this is a correct answer to the old question it doesn't apply the updated question because code was removed from the question. There was a second line `.setData(["JokeNum" : dadJokeNum + 1], merge: false)` which wrote data to the same document immediately after the first write.